# .Net 5 RC 1.20451 Blazor App Fails to launch

Tags: visual-studio, blazor, blazor-webassembly, .net-5

I realise this is pretty 'bleeding edge' stuff so no complaints. I just wonder if anyone else is having the same issue. I am trialing .Net 5 Blazor Web Assembly and have been expanding out from the template app. Local server with built in auth. I have reached a point, size, complexity.. hard to pin down where the app just crashes out when trying to run a debug build. It seems to kill the .NET Host because if I go and remove it using task manager, with a clean start, I can then run it just fine -once.
On the second occasion there is an exception and the launch adapter fails to start.. see the two errors in the image:
[image: VS Null exception error]

There is very little more information since it has failed in 'external code' and I can't get to it to see if I have set something up incorrectly as a null ?
This error message came from the 'Copy Details link':

[image: Exception]

Any ideas anyone... I was hoping the RC would be about ready for primetime, but I realise that is why it is a release candidate...
I am using VS 2019 16.8.0 Preview 3.2

Comment: It is a known issue - I can't find the issue on github but I know it's been reported

Comment: I couldn't find it either. Also, couldnt find where to report it so put it out here... Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/25887 - should be fixed in RC2